# How to show that we have a maximum point.

Tags: real-analysis

Lets say that we want to show that $x^*$ is a local maximum point. Then we can **look at the Taylor-expansion, and lets also assume that the** **linear part of the taylor expansion vanishes**.

**And that we are left with:**

**$f(x^*+\zeta)=f(x^*)+1/2\ \zeta^T\ Hf(x^*)\ \zeta+o(\|\zeta^2\|)$.**

**$Hf(x)$ is the Hessian.**

**We are also given that $\zeta^T\ Hf(x^*)\ \zeta <0$.**

**Why does it then follow that $x^*$ s a local maximum?** I mean it is kind of intuitive since we are given that  $\zeta^T\ Hf(x^*)\ \zeta <0$ so that we we move a little from $x^*$ we will get a negative part, but how do we show that it may not be a bigger positive part from $o(\|\zeta^2\|)$?

I know that $o(\|\zeta^2\|)$, means that $o(\|\zeta^2\|)=h(\zeta)$, where $h(\zeta)/\zeta^2$ goes to zero as $\zeta$ goes to zero. So if I choose $\zeta$ very small, this part will be very small, but still, how do I show that if $\zeta$ is very small, then $h(\zeta)$ will not be bigger in absolute value than $1/2\zeta^T\ Hf(x^*)\ \zeta$?

The problem is that when $\zeta$ is very small, then $\zeta^T\ Hf(x^*)\ \zeta$ may be very small in absolute value aswell, so I don't seee how to show that this part "wins" over the $o(\|\zeta^2\|)$-part?

PS: I tried using the operator norm, and that $|\zeta^T\ Hf(x^*)\ \zeta|\le|\zeta|^2\|Hf(x^*)\|$. But I didn't manage to solve it using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:
You have mentioned $|\zeta^T\ Hf(x^*)\ \zeta|\le|\zeta|^2\|Hf(x^*)\|$, but what about $|\zeta^T\ Hf(x^*)\ \zeta|\ge\cdots$? The key point is that $Hf(x^*)$ is negative definite, and thus all eigenvalues are negative.

Comment: Hello, thanks. But I do not see how to get a lower bound on the quantity? I get that all eigenvalues are negative, but I do not see where to go from there.

Comment: Suppose $\lambda$ is the largest eigenvalue. Then $|\zeta^T\ Hf(x^*)\ \zeta|\ge|\lambda|\cdot|\zeta|^2$.